# qgis 3.0.3 single layer multiple items

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm new to Qgis. Can I use similar items in the SAME layer, with each distinguished by color? For example, different crops in one layer (corn, wheat, barley...) while, a different layer would distinguish among different animals (cattle, pigs, poultry...)

Answer (score 2):

In the properties of your layer, under `Style` tab, use a `Categorized` render and choose the attribute you want to style.

[image]